# How to allocate all memory at beginning of app and then typecast it accordingly throughout

Tags: c, memory, casting, void-pointers

I need to allocate all the memory my application will use up front.  And then whenever needed overwrite that memory with data I need to do computations on.  The memory *has* to be allocated first before any computations because I'm trying to run a multi-threaded CUDA algorithm in parallel as explained in my question here ([Multi-Threaded CPU CUDA application not asynchronous when calling CudaFree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20204936/multi-threaded-cpu-cuda-application-not-asynchronous-when-calling-cudafree)).

I thought I could allocate all the memory needed as a byte pointer and then store that pointer as a void pointer:

```
void * allocateMemory()
{
    byte *mem;
    int nbytes = 13107200;
    mem = (byte *) malloc(nbytes);
    return mem;
}
```

Later in my program I want to use the memory that's already allocated to store data.  I don't know ahead of time what type the data will be but I know it's size won't go over the allocated limit.

```
void doSomething(void * mem)
{
    int *a = (int*) mem;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        a[i] = i;
    }

    //do stuff

}
```

There are many other functions like doSomething(void * mem) above but that use type double or type float or maybe even type byte.  I need to be able to overwrite the orignally allocated memory with whatever data type I need.  The above code does not work because it says I can't deference a void pointer.  It also says I attempted to read or write protected memory.

What is the proper way to do this?  What is the best way to accomplish my goal of having all my memory allocated at the beginning and then used however necessary throughout?  Thanks!

Comment: You're trying to implement a fixed size heap.. not an easy problem to solve with fragmentation etc. Best bet is to use a pool, perhaps using boost which already has this.

Comment: Just saw your other question and I think you've misunderstood the answer. What he is saying is do malloc, loop, free, not begin loop, malloc, free, end loop.

Comment: I have done something similar to this in the past where objects are more or less permanently allocated in a contiguous storage area.  Fairly easy if you have no need to deallocate/reuse.  If you want to be able to deallocate/reuse then you're implementing your own heap (and for that I recommend a Cartesian tree).

Comment: (At the very least, though, you need to maintain a "next" pointer that gives the next byte to allocate, and probably also a "max" pointer/length that tells you when you've blown your allocation.)

Comment: (And I suspect that your immediate problems have to do with some misunderstanding of pointer notation.  That and failing to check the value coming back from `malloc` to see if it's null.)

Comment: Why you need malloc? If you need variables up front - just declare them at the beginning like **char mem[size];** later you may use it as you like with pointers.

Comment: @Artur my apologies.  I simplified the problem so as not to confuse people.  In reality I'm using Cuda so I will need to do cudaMalloc to allocate memory on the device.  The GPU has very few constant memory so I'd have to use cudaMalloc to allocate dynamically.  I did this example in malloc because I felt the question about transferring pointers wasn't directly related to Cuda.  I'm sorry about the confusion I caused.

Comment: @HotLicks I don't need to deallocate. I need to overwrite previous values in the allocated memory with new values but my program is to run on a production line 24/7 so the program will never end. So I shouldn't need to worry about memory leaks. I am almost certain that my problems have something to do with my misunderstanding of pointer notation. lol I keep looking this over though and it makes sense to me. In my mind "a" should be the same address "mem" was and thus I should be able to write over it. I've overwritten memory on accident before. Now that I want to do it on purpose it fails. :/

Comment: What you show above is perhaps not the cleanest, cleverest way to do it, but it should work.  I suspect that your problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have two problems.

1. Cannot dereference a void pointer.  Somewhere in your code you have used the result from `allocateMemory()` without a cast.  The code you give is OK, but whatever line the compiler is flagging as wrong is not OK.  For example, maybe you have:

   ```
   void *foo = allocateMemory();
   foo[42];  // compiler doesn't have a real type here - error
   ((int*)foo)[42];  // compiler happy
   ```
2. Attempted to access protected memory.  Somewhere in your code you have an invalid pointer.  The most likely cause is that `allocateMemory()` is returning NULL (which you are not checking for).

Your general approach seems OK to me; the issues you describe are related to details in your code, not the overall idea.

Comment: Wow I feel dumb. lol I combed through my code and found that it was a copy paste error.  I have ptr1, ptr2, ptr3, and ptr4 set to allocateMemory().  I accidentally did ptr2 twice so ptr3 never had memory allocated to it.  I'm guessing that caused the access protected memory issue when trying to use ptr3.  I'm not sure why I had the dereference a void pointer issue but after fixing the previous mistake and cleaning up my code here and there I no longer have any errors.  Thank you!